# High Current Split Supply

Tags: power-supply, current, split

I am looking for a way to construct a 1 A, ±15 V split-supply. So far, I've seen a number of designs for split-supplies (http://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html), but they are all low current (i.e. 100-300 mA).

My application involves several Mass Flow Controllers that each require a +15 V, 0V, and -15V connection. The data sheet says they draw 300+ mA when in operation (they contain a small heating element).

I attempted two separate solutions using an LM7815 and a LM7915 (one with and without the voltage divider), but they did not work.

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction of an appropriate circuit?

Answer (score 1):

While I am yet to find a satisfactory answer to my question--I'm still digging--I found the attached circuit on Reddit, and plan on trying it out.

http://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/16owyj/heres_a_rail_splitter_circuit_30v_in_15v_out_aka/

[image]

I'm cautious about using a buck converter, because (1) I haven't worked with them before, and (2) having a plus/minus buck converter set up is a very complex place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If the load draws 300mA you would be wasting 19.5-15*0.3=1.35Watt on each power supply.

I would suggest using buck or buck boost converters instead. Have a look at [this app note on how to configure a buck converter for negative voltages](http://www.aosmd.com/res/application_notes/power-ics/PIC-002.pdf).

I think the LM2576 datasheets also have some information on negative configurations.

Comment: Crap, my link looks bad. I'm on a bad phone in the outback, sorry.

Comment: According to my understanding of the circuit, the LM7815 only sees 19.5 V between its 'in' and 'gnd' pins (i.e. 39 V / 2)?

Comment: Well it looks like read your question too fast! I will edit accordingly. I would still opt for a switched regulator.